# How to add userprofile to UserDetailsSerializer in django

Tags: django-rest-framework, user-profile, django-serializer

Trying to add `userprofile` to `user` model

**using**:
 django rest framework. 
rest-auth module 
But line `profile = instance.userprofile` giving **error**:
`*** django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no userprofile.`

**following instructions from [here](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/docs/faq.rst)**

Also, not sure on what is happening in `super` statement

**Possible errors:**
1.`instance` is not having `userprofile` after the `super` statement, hence 
`profile = instance.userprofile` statement giving error
2.`userprofile` needs to be added to `UserDetailsSerializer`

**UserDetailsSerializer**

```
class UserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
        read_only_fields = ('email', )
```

**UserSerializer**

```
class UserSerializer(UserDetailsSerializer):

    company_name = serializers.CharField(source="userprofile.company_name")

    class Meta(UserDetailsSerializer.Meta):
        fields = UserDetailsSerializer.Meta.fields + ('company_name',)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('userprofile', {})
        company_name = profile_data.get('company_name')

        instance = super(UserSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)

        # get and update user profile
        profile = instance.userprofile
        if profile_data and company_name:
            profile.company_name = company_name
            profile.save()
        return instance
```

Do ask for more clarity if required.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Answers don't come instantly. And you are trying to update a profile object which doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes i understand. That is why, i want to know how to add this `userprofile` into `UserDetailsSerializer`. I have modified the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32550317/how-to-define-a-userprofile-into-userdetialsserializer)

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/docs/faq.rst) it is assumed that userprofile was already created and now can be updated. You just need a check

```
# get and update user profile
    try:
        profile = instance.userprofile
    except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
        profile = UserProfile()
    if profile_data and company_name:
```