# how to define a userprofile into UserDetialsSerializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, user-profile, django-serializer

I want to be able to access a `userprofile` instance through :
`profile = instance.userprofile` statement in `UserSerializer`

`instance` is created through:
`instance = super(UserSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)` statement in 
`UserSerializer`

Since `UserSerializer` is inheriting `UserDetailsSerializer`, i think i should define a `userprofile` in `UserDetailsSerializer`. 
 
But i dont know how to do it ?

**Question:** How to define `userprofile` in `UserDetailsSerializer` to achieve the above ?

**UserSerializer:**

```
class UserSerializer(UserDetailsSerializer):
    company_name = serializers.CharField(source="userprofile.company_name")

    class Meta(UserDetailsSerializer.Meta):
        fields = UserDetailsSerializer.Meta.fields + ('company_name',)  

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('userprofile', {})
        company_name = profile_data.get('company_name')

        instance = super(UserSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)

        # get and update user profile
        profile = instance.userprofile
        if profile_data and company_name:
            profile.company_name = company_name
            profile.save()
        return instance
```

**UserDetailsSerializer:**

```
class UserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()

        fields = ('username','email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
        read_only_fields = ('email', )
```

**UserProfile** model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    # custom fields for user
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Do ask if more clarity is required?

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you want a serializer methodfield to be part of your serializer? (I don't full understand your question);

```
class UserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_related = serializers.Field(source='method_on_userprofile')
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('username','email', 'first_name', 'user_related', )
        read_only_fields = ('email', 'user_related',)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have answered similar one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42681151/3174962)

In the [documentation](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/docs/faq.rst) it is assumed that userprofile was already created and now can be updated. You just need a check

```
# get and update user profile
    try:
        profile = instance.userprofile
    except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
        profile = UserProfile()
    if profile_data and company_name:
```